# Regex to remove everything, but emojis from the string in R?

Tags: r, regex, twitter, unicode, emoji

I have a big .xlsx file containing tweets with emojis. I am working on a personal project where I want to make a network graph from the extracted emojis. For example, if I have this in one of the columns:

```
Christian✝️, Husband, Father‍‍‍, Former TV Meteorologist, GOP, LTC , Dolfan, since ‘75, Yanks Fan⚾️ & UCONN Alum Go Whalers!
```

So how would I only get this as on output?

```
✝️‍‍‍⚾️
```

I have looked thoroughly everywhere, in Stack Overflow and over the internet, however I couldn't find anything. I am a beginner in R.

### Edit

I am getting the Unicode (in UTF-8 format) when I normally read the file, but I don't know how to turn those Unicode to the emojis. There are dictionaries online, but they only give me the name of some of these emojis, they are very outdated.

### Edit 2

There is a solution that works in Linux, but I am seeking a solution/hint to get this to work in the Windows.

Comment: Try removing all the chars in BMP, `gsub("[\\x{0000}-\\x{FFFF}]+","",x, perl=TRUE)`

Comment: Many thanks for your response, I really appreciate it. I ran it in one of the narrow column and have received the everything properly. Only problem now is, in the console I am getting like `"\U0001f4da\U0001f921"` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for me, with the caveat only the cross prints out as an emoji in the console, the rest are the unicode representation.

```
# install.packages("remotes")
# remotes::install_github("hadley/emo")
emojis <- "Christian✝️, Husband, Father‍‍‍, Former TV Meteorologist, GOP, LTC , Dolfan, since ‘75, Yanks Fan⚾️ & UCONN Alum Go Whalers!"
emojis
only_emojis <- emo::ji_extract_all(emojis)
only_emojis

#  emo::ji_extract_all(emojis)
# [[1]]
#  [1] "✝️"      "\U0001f46b"      "\U0001f468"      "\U0001f469"      "\U0001f466"      "\U0001f466"      "\U0001f4fa"      "\U0001f418"      "\U0001f52b"      "\U0001f42c"      "\u26be" "\U0001f3c0"      "\U0001f40b"   

# install.packages("utf8")
utf8::utf8_print(only_emojis[[1]])  
# [1] "✝️​" "​" "​" "​" "​" "​" "​" "​" "​" "​" "⚾​" "​" "​"
```

Comment: Hello, thank you. I actually did this came across this package, and had similar error. I have took all of the spaces out of each rows of strings, did same thing, I also asked mr. Wickham in the twitter, haven't received any response yet :(

Comment: I've updated the answer, so it works properly on Linux, but fails on Windows...
According to the utf8 package vignette, Characters with codes above 0xffff, including most emoji, are not supported on Windows.

Comment: Oh no. It's OK, I will use a virtual box if this works in the Linux. At least it is something that progresses my project, I've been stuck in this stage since ages. Thanks a million friend.

Comment: That's pretty surprising even though Windows 10 now supports emoji and has whole emoji keyboard dedicated to it.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking at that too. My wildly flailing guess is that it uses a new Windows API, while R uses older pieces of the API.

Comment: Most likely that could be the case. I will work with what we have, no worries. I will continue to expand this project, so hopefully one day both will catch up. Thanks ^1000